# how to resize images in Titanium without blurring the image

Tags: android, ios, titanium, image-resizing

I have sume beg images that I need to resize to a very small size. When I set my image view to the pretended size like this:

```
view.add(Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image : "/images/icon-menu.png",
    height : deviceHeight * 0.05,
    width : deviceHeight * 0.05
}));
```

the image loses quality. How can I resize the image without losing the image quality? I need something that works on Android and IOS